# Is there anyone has this issue with RN 0.18.0's Devtool?

Tags: react-native

I used a iPhone 4 and a iPhone 6 to test a very simple APP, if there is anything unusall is I listen keyboard event.

```
componentWillMount:function() {
        StatusBarIOS.setHidden( true);

        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardDidShow',(frames)=>{
            console.log( "keyboardDidShow frames: " + frames );

        });
        DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillHide',(frames)=>{
            console.log( "keyboardWillHide frames: " + frames );
        });
    },
```

when I activated Devtool, the Chrome is full with this message and it keeps coming.
there's no way to see any my log info with this endless warning.

```
Running application "Project18" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1766ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
3YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1766ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1762ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1766ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1766ms) should be positive
3YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
2YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1764ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
2YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1766ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1765ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1770ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1735ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1767ms) should be positive
YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
2YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1769ms) should be positive
3YellowBox.js:57 jsSchedulingOverhead (-1768ms) should be positive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. It's kind of odd that they repeatedly show you a warning like this (no context, and no way to Google it and figure out how to solve it).

My "solution" is not a solution, but rather I just disabled the warning. You can find the offending [code here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/Modules/RCTTiming.m#L179). So, as a quick-fix, you can go to `node_modules/react-native/React/Modules/RCTTiming.m`, find the offending line (for me it was on line 187) and just comment it out.

```
if (jsSchedulingOverhead < 0) {
  // RCTLogWarn(@"jsSchedulingOverhead (%ims) should be positive", (int)(jsSchedulingOverhead * 1000));

  /**
   * Probably debugging on device, set to 0 so we don't ignore the interval
   */
  jsSchedulingOverhead = 0;
}
```

It will solve it until you decide to upgrade React Native again.

It might be worth keeping an eye out for a solution that actually solves the problem instead of shooting the messenger, but this should get you back up and running for now.